# Проверка загрузки @font-face

Tags: css3, шрифты, html, javascript

Как проверить, загрузился ли шрифт, который подключается через `@font-face`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никак.

Answer (score 0):

В Хроме можно посмотреть, открыв инструменты разработчика во вкладке ресурсы.

Answer (score 0):

В Хроме

1. `F12` вкладка `Network`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. `F12` > `Elements` > `Computed` пролистываешь в самый низ и смотришь какой шрифт используется у элемента

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: и вас ни капельки не смутил тот факт, что вопрос был задан более 11 лет назад?

Comment: вдруг кому то актуально